# How to automate a particular process, like open a website daily in an android device?

Tags: android, apk, mobile-application, smartphone, mobile-phones

I need to run a specific task in my android device daily.
For example if I want to open a website everyday at a particular time, can I automate this process?

Is there anything like **Cronjob** of Ubuntu or
**windows task scheduler** in Android?

Is there already any Applications for this task in *Android play-store*?

or

can we Use any kind of scripting for this task?

Kindly suggest any solutions for the problem,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the App "Automate". You can do much more with it.
Or Try Ifttt it's very simple.

Comment: installed that application and it seems like little bit complicated.Can you just suggest any reference or any idea for loading a task everyday, for example simply loading a site.

Comment: @ADARSHK Then Try ifttt.com